# How do I remove peaks with Reaper

Tags: guitar, recording

I have recorded an audio track with reaper and set it to record guitar but before I started playing the guitar made some noise and it was recorded.

How can I remove this?

Comment: Ill-formed: there are tons of audio-editing apps which can do this.  Please take at least a *little* time to read the help files in whatever tool you have before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to trim the audio file you recorded.

First you want to [turn off snapping](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=pw9hv13cHNk#t=252) so that you can trim and not snap to the grid that you are using.

Then you hover the mouse over the front edge of the clip and you should get a little icon thing then you can [click and hold then drag and drop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=pw9hv13cHNk#t=341) the beginning to where you need it.